# how do I exit the main program after using process.start?

Tags: vb.net

I have a working vb.net program that simply uses `process.start(MPC-HC.exe)` to automatically play sequentially a text file listing of music files.  All is well unless the user wishes to stop playing any further music while the list isn't finished.

After updating the code as suggested there is still 1 problem:
As I want the music to play automatically without user intervention - I need to specify the player close after each selection is finished playing on its own. This can be done with command line switches "/play /close".

How do I:

1. specify the player to use.
2. add the command line switches

In my original code, I used -

```
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = OpenWith
    startInfo.Arguments = f
```

Where

```
OpenWith = "C:\Program Files\mpc-hc\mpc-hc.exe"
f = vbDoubleQuote + TextLine + vbDoubleQuote + " /play /close"
```

How do I accomplish these things with process ?

Thanks,

Russ

Here is the updated vb.net code with the suggested answer :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    If OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists Then
        filePaths = New Queue(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))

        'Execute the first file.
        process = Process.Start(filePaths.Dequeue())
        Process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub process_Exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles process.Exited
    If filePaths.Count = 0 Then
        'No more files to execute.
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        'Execute the next file.
        Process = Process.Start(filePaths.Dequeue())
        Process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's because you are blocking the UI thread by doing `.WaitForExit()`. You need to respond to the `Exited` event to know when to move to the next file.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding - To be clear I can't exit the Main Application because I'm using .WaitForExit()? As written this was necessary to not have music files play all at once & have too many open files. Please explain further about how I "respond to Exited event".

Comment: jmcilhinney's answer is what I'm suggesting.

Comment: It's presumably a few years too late but I have updated my answer to address this specific scenario. In future, it's better to leave a comment AFTER adding an update, so people know to go and look.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a loop and call `WaitForExit` in it.  Instead, place the items in a `Queue`, dequeue the next item, call `Process.Start` and then handle the `Exited` event of the `Process`.  In the event handler, dequeue the next item and do the same again.  E.g.

```vb
Private WithEvents process As Process
Private filePaths As Queue(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    filePaths = New Queue(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines("source file path here"))

    'Execute the first file.
    process = Process.Start(filePaths.Dequeue())
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub process_Exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles process.Exited
    If filePaths.Count = 0 Then
        'No more files to execute.
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        'Execute the next file.
        process = Process.Start(filePaths.Dequeue())
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT:

I assume that this was either resolved or discarded some years ago but I thought I'd add this for completeness.

It seems that the OP simply copied my EXAMPLE code without understanding what it actually did and they simply ignored how they were already starting their processes. The point of an example, is to demonstrate a principle and, here, that principle was using an event to start multiple processes is serial without blocking the UI. How you actually start the process depends on the specific scenario. In this case, the OP needed to run the same executable every time and pass commandline arguments to it, but simply threw that away in their hurry to copy and paste. What they should have done was replace this:

```vb
process = Process.Start(filePaths.Dequeue())
```

with this:

```vb
process = Process.Start(executablePath,
                        String.Format("""{0}"" /play /close", filePaths.Dequeue())
```

where `executablePath` contained `"C:\Program Files\mpc-hc\mpc-hc.exe"`.

Comment: It only played the 1st file (with associated player "VLC.exe"). Do I need to call process_Exited to play further music?

Comment: It only played the 1st file (with associated player "VLC.exe"). Do I need to call process_Exited to play further music? Also it gave an error saying VLC requested to terminate in an unusual way after the 1 title. It never loaded the second. I was using MPC-HC because it allowed me to start / stop each title through command line arguments. How do I force using that player vs default player?

Comment: As it was, the `Process` object wasn't actually raising the `Exited` event.  I've adjusted my code example to fix that.  The `EnableRaisingEvents` property is now set to `True` for each new `Process`.  The rest of your questions are out of scope.

Comment: OK, it still plays only 1 song and stops. Back to my original problem, I tried to Exit the Main program, while the VLC player was running the 1st file. I could not close it using the regular means.

Comment: I suspect that you have done something wrong but it's not possible to say without seeing your code.  You should update your question with your new code and any other relevant new information.

Comment: I've tested my code with a text file containing a list of text file paths and it works as expected. Each file opens in Notepad as the previous one is closed and the application exits when the last one is closed.  Also, the application can be closed manually at any point. I suggest that you try your code with text files the same way. If it works then the code is sound as is. Are you actually closing VLC in between? If not then the process is not exiting so you will not see an `Exited` event raised in your application. That should still not prevent your app being closed though.

Comment: I will post my updated code tomorrow, as it's at work. I hope you can spot the error(s) that don't allow it to play music as I'd like.